# What is the difference between tags oracle-apps and oracleapplications?

Tags: support, synonym-request

I don't have the rep to suggest synonyms but think the [oracle-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-apps) and [oracleapplications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracleapplications) tags are basically the same. Can we synonymize them?

Comment: For clarity, you could [edit] your question to put the tags in the title in brackets as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like oracle-apps focuses more on the business side of the applications, and oracleapplications is more of an umbrella over all oracle applications and their purposes.